# SQL ending price with 5

Tags: sql

I'm having a problem with a round. 
I need to round prices to end with 5.

Example 1: 647,927 needs to end with 5 with tax. So it should be 815.
647,927 * 1,25 (tax) is 809,90 how can i round 809,90 up to 815

Example 2: 283,30 needs also to end with 5 with tax. So it should be 355.
283,30 * 1,25 (tax) is 354,125 how can i round 354,125 up to 355?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arithmetic.  Something like:

```
select ceiling( (val - 5) / 10 ) * 10 + 5
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c9999579e98762e6b0b8c0c2e286c772) is a db<>fiddle for your two examples.